# Remove the Last Vowel in Python

Tags: python, string

I have the following problem and I am wondering if there is a faster and cleaner implementation of the `removeLastChar()` function. Specifically, if one can already remove the last vowel without having to find the corresponding index first.

***PROBLEM***

Write a function that removes the last vowel in each word in a sentence.

Examples:

`removeLastVowel("Those who dare to fail miserably can achieve greatly.")`

"Thos wh dar t fal miserbly cn achiev gretly."

`removeLastVowel("Love is a serious mental disease.")`

"Lov s  serios mentl diseas"

`removeLastVowel("Get busy living or get busy dying.")`

"Gt bsy livng r gt bsy dyng"

Notes: Vowels are: a, e, i, o, u (both upper and lowercase).

***MY SOLUTION***

*A PSEUDOCODE*

1. Decompose the sentence
2. For each word find the index of the last vowel
3. Then remove it and make the new "word"
4. Concatenate all the words

**CODE**

```
def findLastVowel(word):
    set_of_vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
    last_vowel=''
    for letter in reversed(word):
        if letter in set_of_vowels:
            last_vowel = letter
            break
    return last_vowel
 
def removeLastChar(input_str,char_to_remove):
    index = input_str.find(char_to_remove)
    indices = []
    tmp_str = input_str
    if index != -1:
        while index != -1:
            indices.append(index)
            substr1 = tmp_str[:index]
            substr2 = tmp_str[index+1:]
            tmp_str = substr1+"#"+substr2
            index = tmp_str.find(char_to_remove) 
        
        index = indices[-1]
        substr1 = input_str[:index]
        substr2 = input_str[index+1:]
        return (substr1+substr2)
    else:
        return (input_str)

def removeLastVowel(sentence):
    decomposed_sentence = sentence.split()
    out = []
    for word in decomposed_sentence:
        out.append(removeLastChar(word,findLastVowel(word)))
    print(" ".join(out))


#MAIN
removeLastVowel("Those who dare to fail miserably can achieve greatly.")
removeLastVowel("Love is a serious mental disease.")
removeLastVowel("Get busy living or get busy dying.")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Thos wh dar t fal miserbly cn achiev gretly.
Lov s  serios mentl diseas.
Gt bsy livng r gt bsy dyng.
```

***QUESTION***

Can you suggest a better implementation of the  `removeLastChar()` function? Specifically, if one can already remove the last vowel without having to find the corresponding index first.

Comment: Because your code works, you should probably post this question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I didn't know about it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be more easily achieved with a regex substitution that removes a vowel that's followed by zero or more consonants up to a word boundary:

```
import re

def removeLastVowel(s):
    return re.sub(r'[aeiou](?=[^\Waeiou]*\b)', '', s, flags=re.I)
```

so that:

```
removeLastVowel("Those who dare to fail miserably can achieve greatly.")
```

returns:

```
Thos wh dar t fal miserbly cn achiev gretly.
```